# ENOENT: no such file or directory, after running npm list -g -depth 0 command

Tags: node.js, npm

After updating my node, whenever I run the command: "npm list -g -depth 0", I get this:

```
+-- @vue/cli@4.2.3
+-- create-react-app@3.4.1
+-- eslint@6.8.0
+-- nodemon@2.0.2
+-- npm-check@5.9.2
+-- webpack@4.42.0
+-- webpack-cli@3.3.11
`-- webpack-dev-server@3.10.3

npm ERR! error in C:\Users\akinw\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\akinw\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\package.json'
npm ERR! error in C:\Users\akinw\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\fsevents: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\akinw\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\fsevents\package.json'
npm ERR! error in C:\Users\akinw\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\akinw\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents\package.json'
```

Please, how do I get rid of the npm ERR! messages?

EDIT: Forgot to add that I also uninstalled the old vue-cli, and then installed the the new @vue/cli

Comment: What version of node have you upgraded to?

Comment: hi @steadweb, i've upgraded to 12.16.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to uninstall all the affected packages: webpack and @vue/cli, and then reinstall them, though this time, I included the --no-optional command.

```
npm install --no-optional -g @vue/cli
```

Initially, I thought the issue was node, and I downgraded my node from the latest version to what I had before, but that didn't work.

It turns out there's a problem with one of the packages that comes with webpack and vue, called **fsevents**. The "--no-optional" command ensures **fsevents** isn't included in the installation.

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem when I was installing @vue/cli. I really tried a lot. I finally found it's because I installed package by using cnpm. When I reinstalled the package use npm command, everything being ok. If you didn't solve your problem, you can try it.